# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to signup using the firebase - `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method, but it returns undefined when I try to log the returned value.

My config file :

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxx",
}

firebase?.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const auth = firebase?.auth()
const firestore = firebase?.firestore()

export { auth, firestore }
```

My signup file:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { auth } from "../firebase"



function Signup(props: Props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")
  console.log({ email, password })



  
  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    console.log("clicked")
    e.preventDefault()
    const res = await auth?.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    
    console.log(res) -> gives undefined
    
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <input value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
          <input value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
          <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Signup
```

I'm using firebase version - 9.6.5

On the Firebase dashboard, I don't see anything getting logged neither I get any error on the console.

I have already read other such answers the solution is mostly around using the right package version/upgrading, deleting node modules or initializing the config carefully. I believe I'm doing these steps right.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help in the right direction would be very helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#web-version-9

Please check the official Doc for v9.
I think your approach corresponds to v8

I am using same approach as yours for v8 and its working Good.

Or you can try to deprecate to v8 and try your code on that.

Comment: thanks, that was the issue. I was using v8 way of doing things not v9

Comment: I’m happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the issue here, v9 documentation changes how we import and use the method,

In the config file,

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"

const firebaseConfig = {
  ....
}

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = getFirestore()

const auth = getAuth()

export { auth, db }
```

```
import { auth } from "../firebase"
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth"


createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((i) => console.log(i))
```

Comment: so, i have to use "then", not "async await" ?

Comment: It's a matter of preference, `async-await` and `.then` does the same thing. Both are used to handle promises